# Update table from another table

Tags: sql-server-2005

Each project i have some roles and manager is one of them.I need to fetch projects with  their managername.I have created Temp Table filled the Project Details.Now i am trying to update manager name.I tried but no luck

```
Update #ProjectTemp 
SET ManagerName= pu.FirstName +' '+pu.LastName
FROM Project_Role pr
Inner join PMuser pu on pr.Userid = pu.Userid
where pr.ProjectId in (Select Projectid from #ProjectTemp)and roleid = 11 and #ProjectTemp.projectid = pr.projectid
```

Comment: And what is your question? (Apart from the fact that `user` is a keyword and must be quoted: `[user]`)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script seems correct, only one condition in the `WHERE` clause is probably redundant:

```
pr.ProjectId in (Select Projectid from #ProjectTemp)
```

But it shouldn't affect the result, I understand.

Also there is no table alias before `roleid`. Which table or tables have this column? If there are more than one of them, your script won't run until you specify the proper alias.

Please add more details and elaborate more on your 'no luck'.

Answer (score 0):

The table you UPDATE must be SELECTed from:

```
UPDATE #ProjectTemp 
SET ManagerName= pu.FirstName +' '+pu.LastName
FROM #ProjectTemp 
INNER JOIN Project_Role pr ON pr.ProjectId = #ProjectTemp.ProjectId
INNER JOIN PMuser pu ON pr.Userid = pu.Userid
WHERE roleid = 11
```